# SQL query with dynamic parameters

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, ado

I tried to get some data from DB. I need get account information from my table - this type of information will depend on User. If he/she will insert **account type** = 1 -> he will get this information. How could I create query if it will depend on user: for example user could choose one or more account types and how would show my query?
Now I have something like:

```
SELECT accountID, accountName,AccountNo,accountType from account_ref
where accountType not in (4, 9) and accountType IN (1, 2, 3)
```

But account type could be one or not.

EDITED:
Okey, If I try to set this property from my program (it is c#)
In this case I created method: input parameters - it is list with AccountType(Which user turned)
How could I set it dynamically

```
        public async Task<IList<AccountInfo>> GetAccountByAccountType(IList<AccountType> item)
        {
            //item

            string query = $"SELECT accountID, accountName, AccountNo, accountType from account_ref " +
                            "where accountType not in (4, 9) and accountType IN(1, 2, 3)";

            var accType = await Connection.QueryAsync<AccountInfo>(query);

            return accType.ToList();
        }
```

Comment: Do you use MySQL or SQLServer ?

Comment: *`accountType = 1 or 2 or 3`* - this is wrong, must be `accountType IN (1, 2, 3)`. And this makes `accountType not in (4, 9)` excess.

Comment: I use SQLServer.

Comment: Okay, this implementation is correct, but here is a set 3 parameters **accountType IN (1, 2, 3)**. I wanna set it dynamically. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use IN with comma sepearted values

```
DECLARE @ids NVARCHAR(100) ='1,2,3'    
SELECT accountID, accountName,AccountNo,accountType 
FROM account_ref
WHERE accountType NOT IN (4, 9) 
AND accountType IN (SELECT value from STRING_SPLIT (@ids, ','))
```

Comment: Yeah, I fixed it. But here set my accountType **accountType IN (1,2,3) **. Could I set it dynamically? Because I don't know which parameters will required to user

Comment: In order to make it dynamic you have to pass the given Ids as a parameter to the stored procedure or the query

Answer (score 0):

As per your comments, create a temporary table @AccountType or temp variable and then store the values in it which are getting passed dynamically and then use it like this.

```
INSERT INTO @AccountType
SELECT Value FROM dbo.FncSplitArrayIntoTable(@accountTypeParameter, ',')

SELECT accountID, accountName, AccountNo, accountType 
FROM account_ref
WHERE accountType IN (SELECT accountType FROM @AccountType)
```

FncSplitArrayIntoTable : Implement a custom function to split dynamically passed parameter
with comma-separated values.

Comment: Okey.But If I try to set it using program?

Comment: As you have edited your question, then for your present requirement, this is not a good way to do. Either you use LINQ or create a stored procedure and execute that by passing the parameter from C#.